# New post email (By post type) - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I am trying to setup a function which will send me an email whenever a new post is added to my Wordpress site, I would like to create separate email templates for different post types, so I can customize the email body to fit my needs. I am kind of lost now. I have removed the site email and my email in the code below:

```
function new_post_email($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post_type;

    $to = 'My_email';
    $headers = 'From: wordpress@gokarakter.dk';

    if( $post_type == "lead") {

    $subject_post = 'New lead';
    $body_post    = 'Body text';

    } else {

    $subject_post = 'New post';
    $body_post    = 'Body text';

    }

    wp_mail( $to, $subject_post, $body_post, $headers );
    return $post_ID;
}
add_action('publish_post', 'new_post_email');
```

Comment: And whats your problem? Do you get any error? Or do not you get the mail?

Comment: It works when i am posting a normal post, but it doesent seem to trigger when i post a custom post type post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue a while ago. So This is how I did it.

If you have 2 post types you need to use following code twice.This might not be a good solution.But it's working.

```
<?php 
function notify_new_your_post_type($post_id) {

$to = 'My_email';
$headers = 'From: wordpress@gokarakter.dk';



$subject_post = 'New lead';
$body_post    = 'Body text';

wp_mail( $to, $subject_post, $body_post, $headers );
}
add_action( 'publish_(your_post_type_slug)', 'notify_new_your_post_type' );
?>
```

Comment: Where do you define the post type?

Comment: you said you have post types right ? so replace "your_post_type"  with your one

Comment: Arh okay, so 'publish_(your_post_type_slug)' triggers the action. So 'publish_lead' would trigger when a new lead is added?

Comment: yep. as an example think you have a post type called tenders. in that case your code is look like this.

add_action( 'publish_tenders', 'notify_new_tender' );

remember to use the post type slug for publish_* action

Comment: I'm so glad to help you